# Driving a DC motor in two directions with an opto-isolator

Tags: dc-motor, opto-isolator

i need yo realize a circuit using an opto-isolator to drive a dc motor in 2 directions
i've found this:
[Driving a DC motor (in one direction) with a microcontroller pin and an opto-isolator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/268071/driving-a-dc-motor-in-one-direction-with-a-microcontroller-pin-and-an-opto-iso)
but it is only in one direction.

Comment: search opto isolated h bridge

Comment: thanks you.
i found lot of documents on that.
but i couldn't find a ready PCB design for that, i hope that i can find one, because i'm new in PCB design.

Comment: This forum is for question about individual EE design and theory issues. Questions that are too broad or request directions to specific resources and products are off topic. You can usually get information to help you find what you are looking for, but you will probably need to find or create a complete design on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can always incorporate a h-bridge but that changes the whole dynamic and you have to worry about the gate drive switching times plus most opto-isolators are not capable of the current necessary with high power motors (no motor size is specified, just saying). However, you can rather easily achieve this by using two DPST relays between the micro-controller and the motor. When one relay is triggered the motor turns one direction, when the other relay is triggered the motor will turn the opposite direction. When both relays are released, the motor will stop quickly due to the short acrossed it. This also allows for PWM speed control through the micro-controller if necessary. When using this method you should incorporate an inductive current limiter to reducing sparking at the relays and to help protect the power source from reverse current.